# WPF, Custom Control based on a (Decorator Class), The Decorator's child's Vertical nor Horizontal alignments takes effect when set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I wanted a Custom Control that wraps around its child and adds a four FrameworkElements as (border sides), so I chose a WPF's Decorator Class, both the class and the xaml are in the following github gist.
[Decorator](https://gist.github.com/Youness-ESSalmy/2c30a87ad1ba431cf2f7d0fe234657b8)
The Measurements and Arrangements are as expected, yet the child is always centered to the Decorator even when the its alignments are set.

I tried many things, yet they either ruin the arrangements/measurements or don't work at all, so maybe there is a fundamental problem with my understanding of MeasureOverride & ArrangeOverride or ???.
I want this decorator to function like the Border Class yet has FrameworkElements as a border.

Answer (score -2):

When extending a class like `Decorator` in WPF, understanding how `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` work is crucial because they determine how the child elements are sized and positioned, respectively. In your implementation, you've overridden these two methods, which is correct, but the way you've handled the alignments and arrangement of the child `FrameworkElement` may not be taking into account the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties.

To make your `BorderWrapper` respect the child's `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties (like the standard `Border` class does), you need to adjust how you place the child inside the `ArrangeOverride` method. The `ArrangeOverride` should account for the child's alignment relative to the available space, after allocating space for the "borders".

Here's an adjusted version of your `ArrangeOverride` code snippet that aims to respect the child's alignment properties:

```cs
// The default size & the boundaries of an object
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
{
    // ... (previous code remains the same)

    // Calculate the top-left point where the Child should be arranged, taking alignment into account
    double childLeft = Left != null ? Left.DesiredSize.Width : 0;
    double childTop = Top != null ? Top.DesiredSize.Height : 0;

    // Determine the child's final alignment within the available space
    childLeft += child.HorizontalAlignment switch
    {
        HorizontalAlignment.Center => (childArrangeSize.Width - childDesiredSize.Width) / 2,
        HorizontalAlignment.Right => childArrangeSize.Width - childDesiredSize.Width,
        _ => 0 // Left or Stretch
    };

    childTop += child.VerticalAlignment switch
    {
        VerticalAlignment.Center => (childArrangeSize.Height - childDesiredSize.Height) / 2,
        VerticalAlignment.Bottom => childArrangeSize.Height - childDesiredSize.Height,
        _ => 0 // Top or Stretch
    };

    // Arrange the Child with alignment taken into account
    Point childPos = new Point(childLeft, childTop);
    child.Arrange(new Rect(childPos, childDesiredSize));

    // ... (arranging sides - code remains the same)

    return arrangementSize;
}
```

In this modified version, we determine `childLeft` and `childTop` by considering the horizontal and vertical alignments of the child. The `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of the child can be `Left`, `Center`, `Right` or `Stretch` (same for vertical alignment). If it's `Center`, we place the child in the middle of the available space, minus the space taken by the border sides. For `Right` or `Bottom`, we place it at the end of the available space. `Left` and `Top` will start from the border end, which is effectively `0` distance from the border.

It's essential to remember that the default behavior for `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` is `Stretch`. In that case, the control will stretch to fill the available space (minus the space taken by borders), which may make your borders seem non-effective if you don't actually have any space constraints on the `BorderWrapper`. For non-stretch alignments, this should position the child considering the space occupied by the borders and the chosen alignment.

Make sure to test with different alignments and container sizes to ensure that your control behaves as expected in a variety of scenarios.